# How to interpret results of a latent basis analysis when the estimated lambda exceeds 1?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, growth-model, mplus

I have ran a latent basis analysis and got the results below.

S        BY
AE1                0.000      0.000    999.000    999.000
AE2                0.714      0.185      3.867      0.000
AE3                0.734      0.219      3.348      0.001
AE4                1.024      0.300      3.414      0.001
AE5                1.277      0.304      4.198      0.000
AE6                1.204      0.190      6.331      0.000
AE9                1.000      0.000    999.000    999.000

I got this result using the following code in Mplus,

```
  ! Second-order Intercept, slope loadings for latent basis                             
  i BY AE1@1 AE2@1 AE3@1 AE4@1 AE5@1 AE6@1 AE9@1;                               
  s by AE1@0 AE2* AE3* AE4* AE5* AE6* AE9@1;
```

where slope at time 1 (starting point) and time 9 (final time point) are fixed to 0 and 1 respectively.

I understand that the unconditional results should give me the accumulated growth.
So is it correct that by these results growth at time 4 reaches (slightly exceeds) growth at time 9, growth at time 5 (AE5) exceeds growth at time 9 by 27% (127% of total growth) and time 6 growth reaches 120% of the total growth?
The only examples I have seen in books showed no growth rates exceeding 1.0 so I was wondering if values can be interpreted the same as when they don't.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you fixed the loading of the last time point to one, your slope factor indicates the latent difference (latent change) between Time 1 and Time 9. To make this clear, rather than saying "growth *at* Time 9," I would say "growth *between* Time 1 and Time 9."

Also, the estimated loadings are all fairly close to 1.0 and their standard errors are sizeable. Before making an interpretation about the "% of total growth," I would examine to which extent the (freely estimated) loadings of the other time points are actually statistically different from 1.0. That is, even the loading of 1.277 may not be significantly different from 1.0. You can fix some or all of the slope loadings to 1 and see if there is a significant decline in model fit relative to the model with freely estimated loadings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight. I've tried running the model specifying AET1@0 and AE2-AE9@1 as you pointed out. Then I did a likelihood ratio test (nested model). The results came out as significant. I guess that means I can interpret the accumulated growth as "% of total growth" according to the unstandardized estimates. Please point out if there were any problems in the procedure I took. Thank you again.

Comment: The only issue may be that this constitutes an omnibus test of all free loadings combined. There may still be individual loadings that may not be significantly different from 1 even when the overall nested model difference test is significant. For example, 1.024 is likely not statistically different from 1.0. It may make sense to test some individual loadings with appropriate correction methods for multiple "post hoc" testing. Do you have a specific theory about the growth process?

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking that 1.024 may not be significantly different from 1.0 and the same for time 1 and 2 where the difference is 0.02. In that case, would the post hoc testing be more suitable fitting a piecewise model? I have not yet encountered an example of fixing loadings within the freely estimated loadings. Also, is there a way (or tips) to understand how to gauge the magnitude of standard errors in relation to estimated loadings (like you referred to in the first response)? As for the growth process I'm analyzing, the theory does not have a specific theory of how this factor grows.